# Why is gtag-function not sending an event to Google Analytics?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, quasar-framework

I use the gtag-script for google analytics in a VueJS 3/Quasar application.

In the index.html, I initialize gtag with consent mode and denie eveything. The Idea is, to update the consent setting once the user has confirmed and allowed to store cookies and to send events to Google Analyitcs.
However, nothing happens when I start with "denied" in my gtag.

This is the index.html code:

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXX');
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    'ad_storage': 'denied',
    'ad_user_data': 'denied',
    'ad_personalization': 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
  });
</script>
```

This is the code that I execute upon user-confirmation:

```
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    ad_storage: 'denied',
    ad_user_data: 'granted',
    ad_personalization: 'granted',
  });
```

Sending an event right away:

```
  gtag('event', 'set_consent', {
    param1: 'consent given',
  });
```

I can't see anything in Google Analytics. How to achieve that?

Comment: It would be easiest to use a Vue specific library that implements gtag as a Vue plugin: https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/ It then becomes very easy to use and manipulate gtag from within your app.